# How do I run a sql query on Ambari / Zeplin using a command line tool?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, ambari, beeline

I currently login to our big data Ambari / Zeplin web interface using a username/password in firefox and then execute a sql query and press play.

I was wondering if its possible to connect to the ambari server using the creds and run a sql script via a command line tool from windows CMD.exe , the same way you can do it using sqlplus and oracle databases. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you must be running hive queries by logging into Ambari/Zeppelin.

You can access your hive server through jdbc by entering metastore IP, port and credentials from any jdbc command line utility like beeline.

Basically, your client node/  Edge Node should have the clients for the services(hive/hbase/Spark) and then you can run the queries through dedicated shell.

Comment: from the Ambari web interface, is there anyway to get the metastore IP or where would I find this?

Comment: Login to Ambari, on the left side select Hive, and on the right at the top select Summary. Than click on HiveServer2 to see the host where it's running.